# GCM Multiple messages in the same time

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging, messaging

I am working with **Google Cloud Messaging** (HTTP) with **PHP**, so i have a PHP file that contains a function to send GCM Message.

My question is: if the php script is running by multiple users in the same time which message will be sent or they all will be sent ?

Thank you.

**Example:**

```
gcm.php?message=Hello

gcm.php?message=GoodNews

etc....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which message will be sent or they all will be sent ?

All messages will be sent. Each user that makes a request to your server will have their own separate PHP process assigned to serving that request, meaning all requests are unaware of each other and will work in parallel to fulfill the request.